# I deleted my post, but now want to view its source

Tags: support, editing, deleted-questions

I asked a question, but it was noted in the comments that it was a bit too elementary for this site, and it was suggested that I delete and then post it to Math.SE. I deleted it, and still have the link, but no am I wondering how to access the source of the post since the "edit source" button is highlighted out. I still have access to the post, just not the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have (on your request) migrated it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109909/when-is-it-possible-to-interpret-composition-as-a-natural-transformation), and you should have access to the source. Let me know if you experience any difficulties.

Answer (score 6):

Just by the way: if you want to get the source of your deleted question, there are some ways to do it

- undelete it, click "edit", copy everything you need, delete it
- go to the revisions (mathoverflow.net/posts/{id-of-the-post}/revisions), click "source" in the header of the desired revision